# Damage during jumpstart

Tags: jump-start, damage, fuel-line, electric-vehicle, short

I used my vehicle jump start another vehicle,the other vehicle started then died out, not cables remained on both vehicles for about 20 minutes before realizing the other vehicle died. Now my vehicle refuses to turn over. Could i have damaged something?

Comment: Now you likely need a jump start from another vehicle :-(  It looks like your battery just drained out by the other dead battery. Did you check your battery voltage with a DMM? If you turn your INTERNAL lights on, are they lit? When you crank, do they dim out?

Comment: Along with the excellent questions of @AliChen ... What year/make/model of vehicle is this we're talking about?